# Hex colour not plotting correctly in ggplot2 (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know there are several questions which already ask this question, but I have implemented the solutions to a number of these and not had any luck.

I am using mtcars as an example:

```
mtcars_new <- mtcars %>% 
    mutate(
        colour = case_when(
            gear == 3 ~ "#FFFFFF",
            gear == 4 ~ "#FF7000",
            gear == 5 ~ "#85AEFF"
        )
    )

hm <- ggplot(mtcars_new, aes(cyl, carb, fill = colour)) + 
    geom_tile() +
    scale_colour_identity()
```

This produces this plot, where the colours do not match the hex codes:

[image: heatmap]

I have also tried the following, which did not work:

```
hm <- ggplot(mtcars_new, aes(cyl, carb, fill = colour)) + 
    geom_tile() +
    scale_colour_identity()

hm <- ggplot(mtcars_new, aes(cyl, carb), fill = colour)) + 
    geom_tile()
```

What is the best way to take hex codes from within the df and use it to define the colour?

Comment: You're using `scale_color_identity()` when you should be using `scale_fill_identity()`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set the identity scale by encoding the colour as `asis` in the mapping: `aes(cyl, carb, fill = I(colour))`.